# Connection refused to remote Spark Master running on a Docker Container

Tags: python-3.x, docker, apache-spark

I want to connect to a remote Spark Master running on Docker, via Python in my local machine:

```
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \.
    .master('spark://spark-spark-master:7077') \
    .appName('spark-yarn') \
    .getOrCreate()
```

I get `Connection Refused` error from running the code.

Running `telnet ip 7077` in  my terminal gives the error:

> telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

This is confusing, because the port on the server itself is open and the server is accepting connection from port 7077.

Running `docker container ls` on the server shows:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                  PORTS                                            NAMES
9086cf2f26dc        bde2020/spark-master:3.0.1-hadoop3.2                     "/bin/bash /master.sh"   2 weeks ago         Up 2 weeks              6066/tcp, 8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7077->7077/tcp       spark_spark-master.1.qyie2bq52hbrfg2ttioz6ljwq
5133adc223ef        bde2020/spark-worker:3.0.1-hadoop3.2                     "/bin/bash /worker.sh"   2 weeks ago         Up 2 weeks              8081/tcp                                         spark_spark-worker.ylnj52bj78as9hxr6zdo1lgo3.kwzys14lm3uid0qclyv0jn95o
da2841b1d757        bde2020/hadoop-nodemanager:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8       "/entrypoint.sh /run…"   2 months ago        Up 2 months (healthy)   8042/tcp                                         hadoop_nodemanager.ylnj52bj78as9hxr6zdo1lgo3.o9gznaa9u57wuyf21fl9ya4hi
49a3cbb8073a        bde2020/hadoop-resourcemanager:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8   "/entrypoint.sh /run…"   2 months ago        Up 2 months             8088/tcp                                         hadoop_resourcemanager.1.7kwgmhxz74brj6xs218k81ptk
10b22205a879        bde2020/hadoop-historyserver:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8     "/entrypoint.sh /run…"   2 months ago        Up 2 months (healthy)   8188/tcp                                         hadoop_historyserver.1.p3c3ouxmayxt4rvhrjlq7ti4t
775209433ea8        bde2020/hadoop-namenode:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8          "/entrypoint.sh /run…"   2 months ago        Up 2 months (healthy)   0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9870->9870/tcp   hadoop_namenode.1.bbt0n4ne76ddwqtmejlsf590m
5d14d16020e5        bde2020/hadoop-datanode:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8          "/entrypoint.sh /run…"   2 months ago        Up 2 months (healthy)   9864/tcp                                         hadoop_datanode.ylnj52bj78as9hxr6zdo1lgo3.e9drmfbdqicux6ltkk9gv2uh5
83f7b3290995        traefik:v2.2                                             "/entrypoint.sh --ap…"   2 months ago        Up 2 months             80/tcp                                           traefik_traefik.1.ha8o6dc3ewtmppkn4pauugkj
```

The docker-compose.yml file for spark is:

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  spark-master:
    image: bde2020/spark-master:3.0.1-hadoop3.2
    networks:
      - workbench
    ports:
      - target: 7077
        published: 7077
        mode: host
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.hostname == johnsnow
      labels:
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.docker.network=workbench"
        - "traefik.http.services.spark-master.loadbalancer.server.port=8080"
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env
    environment:
    - INIT_DAEMON_STEP=setup_spark
    - "constraint:node==spark-master"

  spark-worker:
    image: bde2020/spark-worker:3.0.1-hadoop3.2
    networks:
      - workbench
    environment:
      - SPARK_MASTER_URL=spark://spark_spark-master:7077
    deploy:
      mode: global
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
      labels:
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.docker.network=workbench"
        - "traefik.http.services.spark-worker.loadbalancer.server.port=8081"
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env
    environment:
    - INIT_DAEMON_STEP=setup_spark
    - "constraint:node==spark-worker"
networks:
  workbench:
    external: true
```

Why is this error occurring?

Edit: content of spark-spark-master after running `docker network -v workbench`

```
 },
            "0bce286b736b1368738aa7504e1219dd12d855f7d79fc8f17d6a04b98ebe0ec1": {
                "Name": "spark_spark-master.1.2tdsfzhbyl1wr8omjh518lhwg",
                "EndpointID": "ae7e503e911039c3f02469a968536035b88c0213bcf09a1def49eaf7853b9085",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:01:07",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.1.7/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },

...

"spark_spark-master": {
                "VIP": "10.0.1.70",
                "Ports": [],
                "LocalLBIndex": 257,
                "Tasks": [
                    {
                        "Name": "spark_spark-master.1.2tdsfzhbyl1wr8omjh518lhwg",
                        "EndpointID": "ae7e503e911039c3f02469a968536035b88c0213bcf09a1def49eaf7853b9085",
                        "EndpointIP": "10.0.1.7",
                        "Info": {
                            "Host IP": "ip"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
```

Comment: Can you share some details about the `workbench` network? What is the output of `docker network inspect -v workbench`?

Comment: What are you using for `ip`? Should that be `spark_spark-master` or some other hostname instead of an IP?

Comment: @AlexWatt yes I am using spark-spark-master

Comment: @werner I can output the content of spark master alone, since the whole file is pretty big

Comment: How do you create the external network `workbench`? If I create it with `docker network create workbench` and then run your docker-compose.yml, everything works for me. It looks like `workbench` uses the IP range `10.0.1.X`. Are the ip routes set correctly for this network (`ip route`)?

Comment: `spark_spark-master` is only available inside the subnet `workbench`. if you access the spark cluster from an external server, you should use the ip of that host server (as you have `0.0.0.0:7077->7077/tcp` ), try use `spark://host_ip:7077` in your code.

Comment: @jxc I have used it, still connection refused error

Comment: can you run `ping host_ip` or `traceroute host_ip` from your local machine, just to check if the packet from your local machine can reach the destination host server. the issue is more like a network issue between your local machine and the host server or any existing upstream routers. it might also be SeLinux issue if some strict rules were enforced on the host server.

Comment: @jxs I can ping the ip and traceroute, some ports like 8080 and 80 are open, 7077 shows as not. But it is, cause iptables rules show it as open

Comment: @Snow, the network traffic can be blocked on the upstream routers between your local machine and the host server. opening port on the host server alone is not enough except that the host server is exposed to the external world directly or your local machine is on the same subnet with the host.

Comment: @werner I use the same command for creating it: `docker network create -d overlay --attachable workbench`